# data frame information split between columns yet can not merge due to nature of data

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a set of data that comes in 2 files one is the actual data file and the other is the file that describes the data.

The actual file

```
head(actual_data)
       barcode barcode_different_source  Cell_type_1 Cell_type_2
2                          5322084009_E         11.0         4.2                      
3                          5376111038_A         10.8         4.1
4 9423641043_C                                   2.8         5.3                    
5 9423641111_H                                   3.1         3.9                       
6                         94236411133_B          7.2         3.3
```

As for the information file:

```
head(information_file)
          Barcode category
     9423641051_I        A
     9425128011_C        B
     9423641078_J        C
     9425128006_K        D
     9423641080_C        E
     9423641086_F        F
```

I need to use the "match()" command such that I can match the patterns of "Barcodes" between the information and actual data files, my attempt is as follows:

```
   pattern <- match( information_file$Barcode, actual_data$barcode )   
   information <- information[pattern, ]  #to rearrange the row sequence of the information to match that of the actual data file
```

My problem with the above method is that as you can see in the first 2 columns of the actual data file, data is missing be tween them. I would like to be able to match the pattern of the information file with that of the actual data without having to merge these first 2 columns, my problem is that a row in the first 2 columns can both contain information that is non-redundant and I do not want to lose information:

```
                  barcode                barcode_different_source
 1                                                   5322084009_E
 2                                                   5376111038_A
 3           9423641043_C                                        
 4           9423641111_H----------------------------5372311038_V            
 5           9423641049_J              |                          
 6           9423641097_K              |
                                       |
                                 different barcodes but both valid
```

Hence I must account for both barcode sources (i.e. read both columns) without incorrectly matching the pattern of the 2 files.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Your example data doesn't actually include any overlapping barcodes (or did I miss something?) so a bit hard to work on this. Also in your `match` function the column is called `Array.barcode` - is something else missing in data?

Comment: sorry will rectify this- no, the rows in which both columns contain a barcode, the barcodes will be different between these two- but I thing I need to consider both.... so how do I re-arrange the pattern of the information file while considering 2 columns in the actual_data_file

Comment: when you read.table actual_data, how are you setting fill = ?

Comment: sorry it's actually read.xls which also creates data frame- I tried "fill=F" to state that the columns were not even and it seems to have worked